# Redirecting to a specific action on browser back button click MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, back-button, page-refresh

How can I redirect to a controller action when the browser's back button is clicked.
I can achieve this by clicking my own button or link on the page hustle-free but getting the same result from clicking the browser's back or refresh button is an issue.

I have a controller called "Notifications"
An action in the contoller called "Unlock" whick takes "id" as an argument.

My Link works perfectly fine:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Unlock", new { id = Model.NotificationId })
```

I've tried using javascript:

```
    <script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            window.location.replace("/Notifications/Unlock/" + "@Model.NotificationId");
            }
    </script>
```

even window.location.href doesn't seem to work. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this is a really bad practice since it is neither a standard behavior nor is it something that the user expects. You should have very strong arguments for doing that. I don't know if it is even possible to change the history or the behavior of the back button.

Comment: I'm well aware of that thank you. It's just that some action needs to be taken when the user clicks my link. But if they don't and go click the back button... big issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Notifications/Unlock/' + '@Model.NotificationId',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Will this work if the action method being redirected to is of type 'HttpPost' ?

Comment: Mine worked with the  type 'HttpPost' hence I mentioned 'POST' on my ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. When the user presses the back button of the browser, a cached version of the previous page will be rendered and the server will never be called.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better approach than what I'm trying? Because disabling the back button is a definite NO. As much as I'm a developer , I've been a user of other terrible websites which implemented that... jokes

Comment: I think we need more background of the actual problem that you are trying to solve. Then one can think about other approaches. Maybe AJAX calls to an action or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @timmkrause. That gave me an idea.